# Microsoft Teams - 250 user creation limit

Tags: microsoft-teams

Looking at Microsoft Teams thresholds a user cannot create more that 250 teams. Global admins are excluded however and apps calling Microsoft Graph:

"Any directory object in Azure Active Directory counts towards this limit. Global admins are exempt from this limit, as are apps calling Microsoft Graph using application permissions."

As we'll hit this limit fairly quickly we are considering to have a teams provisioning engine where a Managed Identity will be using PnP (New-PnPTeamsTeam). Assumed this approach should then not be hit by the 250-limit?

Anyone having experience of such approach that could confirm if it works and possibly any lessons learned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I can confirm that using Graph (works with PnP as well) and a Service Principal (App Identity) with proper API permissions works and creation of +250 Teams works.

Using a service account you will get errors at Team 251.